# Ajax Base64 Image Response Text

Tags: php, ajax, php-5.3

I am sending ajax request to the server as : 
                 Client Side Code :

```
             <html>
         <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
         <title>Untitled Document</title>
         <script language="">
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

          }

         else
          {
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          var imgVal='img_id'+1;

          xmlhttp.open("GET","imageprovider.php",false);
          xmlhttp.send();

          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
          {


            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById('img').appendChild(xmlhttp.responseText);

          }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id='img'>

    </div>

</body>
```

And here is the server side code that shows a simple image with base64 encode.How can i get the response from client the above code and show it.

```
      Server Side PHP Code :

          <?php 

           $img_src = "images/1.png";

           $imgbinary = fread(fopen($img_src, "r"), filesize($img_src));
           $img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary);
           echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'" />';


          ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
document.getElementById('img').appendChild(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

with

```
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Or, if you need to continue using .appendChild(), try replacing

```
document.getElementById('img').appendChild(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

with

```
var o = document.createElement('img');
o.src = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById('img').appendChild(o);
```

And replacing

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str.'" />';
```

with

```
echo 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_str;
```

Comment: it gives an erro that document.getElementById("img") is null.Any idea why?

Comment: Because your script is running before the browser parses that div.  Either put the code in an `onload` handler, or move that script block to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. you capture the response
2. you inject the response into the DOM

Whith jQuery the code would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "imageprovider.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    $('#objectToAddImage').html(data);
  }
});
```

Nevertheless I would advise against passing the image as a base64 as the browser will have no way to cache it. If passing the image as a base64 encode is not an absolute requirement of your project **I would recommend the server simple pass a link to the actual image**.

Comment: i want to do it using ajax and js only..no jquery...can you help me with that?

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju jQuery as other JS frameworks are js only. The only thing they really do is abstract Javascript in order to make it work across multiple browsers. It's pretty unfortunate but even simple code like the one you are using here may fail some users. Not gonna change the answer as you already had your problem solved.

Comment: I know you suggested a better way.But i was looking for this simple js help actually.For Decoding the base64 response.I tried your approach too and it worked.Thanks man